# Drawing a rotating rectangle around shapely polygon

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, shapefile

i have polygon coordinates and i have plotted a polygon using PolygonPatch. Next up, using moments i have center coordinates (x,y) , height and width(X,Y) and rotation angle (theta). using these parameters i want draw the bounding rectangle around my polygon . i can draw these rotated rectangle using opencv

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

but this only works when i am working on images not on shapley polygon patch. Is there a way i can draw the rotated rectangle around ploygonpatch without converting them to images.

Comment: But in order to draw something, you need to have an image. Do you want the coordinates of rectangle around your "shapely polygon patch"?

Comment: yes, I have the coordinates of shapely polygon patch.

Comment: Can you provide your polygon patch code? I still don't get your intention, you can provide those coordinates to `cv2.minAreaRect`, just as you've shown in your code.

Comment: I can provide the coordinates of the polygon to cv2.minArea but to visualize it using cv2.drawContours i need to pass image as a first argument but i have to work on PolygonPatch.